# Помогите найти выход за пределы массива

Tags: c, многопоточность, winapi

```
/* Функции */
DWORD WINAPI WelcomeThreadF(LPVOID);
DWORD WINAPI InputThreadF(LPVOID);
DWORD WINAPI SafeСycleThreadF(LPVOID);

/* Переменные */
char CPU_cores = 0; // Кол-во ядер
FILE* file;
unsigned long freeth;

// Структура графа
struct graph_my {
    unsigned int* freelist;
    unsigned long count;
    unsigned int** grmatrix;
};

struct graph_my GHT;

// Очередь
struct prlist {
    unsigned int root;
    unsigned int* tail;
    char check;
};

struct prlist* PL;
unsigned long long int PL_count;

Дальше main...
HANDLE* SafeСycleCheck; // Поток вывода экрана приветствия
HANDLE Inputthread; // Поток обработки данных
char fadr[257]; // Aдресс файла

unsigned int first, sec; // Тикер (Для тех. нужд)
unsigned long long int positionnn = 0; // Тикер (Для тех. нужд)
bool found;



// Чтение данных из файл
    fscanf(file, "%u", &first);
    GHT.freelist = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
    GHT.freelist[0] = 0;
    while (first != 0) {
        GHT.freelist[0]++;
        GHT.freelist = (unsigned int*)realloc(GHT.freelist,
            (GHT.freelist[0]+1)*sizeof(unsigned int));
        GHT.freelist[GHT.freelist[0]] = first;
        fscanf(file, "%u", &first);
    }

    // Cчитывание вершин
    GHT.count = 0;
    GHT.grmatrix = (unsigned int**)malloc(2 * sizeof(unsigned int*));
    GHT.grmatrix[0] = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
    GHT.grmatrix[1] = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
    while (fscanf(file, "%u%u", &first, &sec) == 2) {
        if (sec != first) GHT.count++;
        GHT.count++;
        GHT.grmatrix[0] = (unsigned int*)realloc(GHT.grmatrix[0],
            GHT.count*sizeof(unsigned int));
        GHT.grmatrix[1] = (unsigned int*)realloc(GHT.grmatrix[1],
            GHT.count*sizeof(unsigned int));

        if (sec != first) {
          GHT.grmatrix[0][GHT.count - 2] = first;
          GHT.grmatrix[1][GHT.count - 2] = sec;
          GHT.grmatrix[0][GHT.count - 1] = sec;
          GHT.grmatrix[1][GHT.count - 1] = first;
        } else {
          GHT.grmatrix[0][GHT.count - 1] = sec;
          GHT.grmatrix[1][GHT.count - 1] = first;
        }
    }

    // Подготовка
    freeth = ThreadLimit;
    if (freeth > 1)
        freeth--;
    PL = (struct prlist*)malloc(sizeof(struct prlist));
    PL_count = 0;

    // Постановка задач в список
    PL_count = GHT.freelist[0];
    PL = (struct prlist*)realloc(PL, (PL_count)*(sizeof(struct prlist)));
    for (first = 1; first <= GHT.freelist[0]; first++) {
        PL[first - 1].root = GHT.freelist[first];
        PL[first - 1].tail = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
        PL[first - 1].tail[0] = 0;
        PL[first - 1].check = 0;
    }

    // Выполнение задач
    while (positionnn < PL_count - 1) {
        if ((PL_count - 1 - positionnn) < freeth)
            freeth = PL_count - 1 - positionnn;

        SafeСycleCheck = (HANDLE*)malloc(freeth*sizeof(HANDLE));

        for (first = 0; first < freeth; first++) {
            SafeСycleCheck[first] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, SafeСycleThreadF,
                NULL, 0, NULL);
        }

        for (first = 0; first < freeth; first++) {
            WaitForSingleObject(SafeСycleCheck[first], INFINITE);
        }

        free(SafeСycleCheck);

        positionnn = positionnn + freeth;
    }

    // Вывод
    found = false;
    for (positionnn = 0; positionnn < PL_count; positionnn++) {
        if (PL[positionnn].check = 8) {
            found = true;
            printf("Found cycle: ");
            for (first = 1; first <= PL[positionnn].tail[0]; first++) {
                printf("%u%c", PL[positionnn].tail[first], ' ');
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    if (found == false)
        printf("Cycles not found!\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Чекер циклов                                 //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

DWORD WINAPI SafeСycleThreadF(LPVOID t) {
    unsigned long long int positionnn = 0; // Тикер (Для тех. нужд)
    unsigned long long int kek, lol, plc = 0;

    while (PL[positionnn].check != 0)
        positionnn++;
    PL[positionnn].check = 1;

    if (PL[positionnn].tail[0] != 0) {
      for (kek = 1; kek <= PL[positionnn].tail[0]; kek++) {
        if (PL[positionnn].root == PL[positionnn].tail[kek]) 
          PL[positionnn].check = 8;
      }  
    }

    if (PL[positionnn].check != 8) {
        PL[positionnn].check = 2;
        for (kek = 0; kek < GHT.count; kek++) {
            if (GHT.grmatrix[0][kek] == PL[positionnn].root) {
               PL_count++;
               PL = (struct prlist*)realloc(PL, PL_count*(sizeof(unsigned int)));
               plc = PL_count-1;
               PL[plc].check = 0;
               PL[plc].root = GHT.grmatrix[1][kek];
               PL[plc].tail = (unsigned int*)malloc((PL[positionnn].tail[0]+2)*sizeof(struct prlist));
               PL[plc].tail[0] = PL[positionnn].tail[0]+1;
               for (lol = 1; lol < PL[plc].tail[0]; lol++) {
                  PL[plc].tail[lol] =  PL[positionnn].tail[lol];
               }
               PL[plc].tail[PL[plc].tail[0]] = PL[positionnn].root;
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Пример файлика на ввод

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
0
1 1
1 2
2 1
3 3
2 1
6 2
6 3
4 4
3 2
```

Идея следующая
Я задаю сперва вершины графа и матрицу связности
А после добавляю задание в список
Собственно при выполнении `PL[plc].tail = (unsigned int*)malloc((PL[positionnn].tail[0]+2)*sizeof(struct prlist));` получаю вылет за пределы массива.
Можете помочь?
Вот весь код: [(PasteBin)](https://pastebin.com/Xj8KbxEr)

Comment: Воспользуйтесь отладчиком и/или трассировками.

Comment: Пытался - никак не понимаю, где накосячил

Comment: В каком месте происходит выход за пределеы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дикая манера использовать имена типов под `sizeof` в `malloc/calloc/realloc` наносит очередной удар

```
PL = (struct prlist*)realloc(PL, PL_count*(sizeof(unsigned int)));
```

Почему под `sizeof` вдруг сидит `unsigned int`, если память вы выделяете под массив `struct prlist`???

Избавьтесь от страшной манеры повторять одно и тоже по три раза, да еще и с ошибками. Избавьтесь от манеры без явной на то необходимости указывать имена типов в `sizeof`. И никаких приведений типов на результатах функций выделения памяти

```
PL = realloc(PL, PL_count * sizeof *PL);
```

Коротко, ясно. И все сразу было бы в порядке.

---

И далее еще один перл из той же оперы

```
PL[plc].tail = (unsigned int*)malloc((PL[positionnn].tail[0]+2)*sizeof(struct prlist));
```

Здесь уже наоборот...

Причем, что характерно, автор сам же в своем вопросе повторно процитировал эту очевидно бессмысленную строчку, но при этом не разглядел ее бессмысленности.

Comment: А насчет такого подхода с указателеми отдельное спасибо, не знал, что так можно